# from input file to array using malloc and realloc

Tags: c

I am trying to read input from a file and put each string in an array using malloc and realloc. So if the input file is :

```
alex
john
jane
smith
```

the content of array contain {"alex\n", "john\n", "jane\n", "smith\n"}. So far I have done something like this:

```
int n=0;
int size=1;
File *fp = fopen(args[0],"r");
int c;
char* inputFile;
inputFile = (char*) malloc(size);
if(fp==0){
  fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file!\n");
  return -1;}
else{
  do{
    c = fgetc(fp);
    inputFile = (char*) realloc(inputFile, size+1);
    inputFile[n]=c;
    n++;
    size++;
  }while(c!=EOF);
```

I believe this algorithm will end up with array like this {'a','l','e','x','\n','j','o','h','n','\n','j','a','n','e','\n','s','m','i','t','h','\n'}

how can I make the inputFile become 2 dimension array? what should I do with realloc?

Comment: `"Cannot open file!"`  Why not?  `man perror`

Comment: Will your code even compile? `inputFile = char* malloc(size);` is not valid syntax. I think you mean `(char*) malloc(size)`, but you generally shouldn't cast the result of `malloc()` (if you need to do it to prevent a warning, it means you forgot an `#include`).

Comment: @barmar I haven't test it yet, because I am doing it on paper. I dont have c installed computer with me. thx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following or just study how it's done. It works fine on my linux machine. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int INITIAL_MAX_LINES = 2;
const int MAX_LINES_INC = 2;

const int INITIAL_MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 2;
const int MAX_LINE_LENGTH_INC = 2;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int nlines = 0, i;
  FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  char **inputFile, *buffer;
  int max_lines, c, buflen, bufpos, end_of_line;

  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("No enough arguments.\n");
    return -1;
  }

  max_lines = INITIAL_MAX_LINES;

  inputFile = (char **) malloc(max_lines * sizeof(char*));
  if (fp==0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file!\n");
    return -1;
  }
  else{
    /* Start with a buffer. */
    bufpos = 0;
    buflen = INITIAL_MAX_LINE_LENGTH;
    buffer = (char *) malloc(buflen * sizeof(char *));

    c = 0;
    while (c != EOF) {

      end_of_line = 0;

      c = fgetc(fp);

      if (c == EOF || c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
        end_of_line = 1;
       /* Discard this character. */
      }
      else {
        /* Put this character in the buffer. */
        /* But check if we have enough memory first! */
        /* Leave room for the null character at the end. */
        if (bufpos >= buflen - 1) {
          buflen += MAX_LINE_LENGTH_INC;
          buffer = (char *) realloc(buffer, buflen * sizeof(char));
        }
        buffer[bufpos] = c;
        bufpos++;
      }

      if (end_of_line) {
        /* Remember this line and get a new buffer. */
        /* Check if we need more memory. */
        if (nlines >= max_lines) {
          max_lines += MAX_LINES_INC;
          inputFile = (char **) realloc(inputFile, max_lines * sizeof(char*));
        }

        /* Null terminate the buffer.*/
        buffer[bufpos++] = 0;

        inputFile[nlines] = buffer;
        nlines++;

        bufpos = 0;
        buflen = INITIAL_MAX_LINE_LENGTH;
        buffer = (char *) malloc(buflen * sizeof(char *));
      }
    }
  }

  printf("%d lines\n", nlines);
  for (i=0; i<nlines; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", inputFile[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you would want to allocate an array of pointers first with an initial size say 10:

```
int size = 10;
char **inputFile= malloc(sizeof*inputFile*size);
```

Then for each word you read you allocate more memory for it and insert it into the array:

```
char line[100];
fscanf(file, "%s", line);
inputFile[index++] = strdup(line);
```

Now check if you need more words then you realloc the array:

```
if (index==size) {
   size += 10;
   inputFile = realloc(inputFile, sizeof*inputFile*size);
}
```

So you end up with something like this:

```
[0]->"alex"
[1]->"john"
[2]->"jane"
[3]->"smith"
```

When you're done you need to loop over the array and free each string and then free the array, this part is left as an exercise :)

Comment: Okay. I got it. thx. But how can I realloc the second dimension of the array? Eg. I want to realloc the inputFile[1]? is it inputFile[1] = realloc(inputFile[1],sizeOf*inputFile*size)?

Comment: @EldwinH no this one needs `sizeof**inputFile` because it's a pointer to a pointer to char. generally, you realloc anything by doing `pointer = realloc(pointer, newsize)`

Comment: So, when I want to realloc the pointer array inside the array, I need to realloc the whole array? because I think 2D array is something like this {{...},{...},{...}} So, when I try to realloc one of the inner array, I only need to realloc that particular inner array.

Comment: @EldwinH no you don't need to realloc the entire array, you need to do that only if you need more elements. Don't forget to upvote and accept if this helps.

Comment: can't upvote yet (still got less than 15 rep). So if I only want to realloc the inner array, I only need to realloc(pointer to inner array, newsize) right?